# Swift: How to delete last added duplicate

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am using a tableview to let people Rate different Items using Cosmos. 
Whenever a user Rates an Item e.g. Productivity, the value will be added to an array:

```
class RatingItem {

    var key: String?

    var item: String
    var rating: Double

    init?(item: String, rating: Double) {

            // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
            // The name must not be empty
            guard !item.isEmpty else {
                return nil
            }

            // The rating must be between 0 and 5 inclusively
            guard (rating >= 0) && (rating <= 7) else {
                return nil
            }

            // Initialize stored properties.
            self.item = item
            self.rating = rating

        }
    var dictValue: [String: Any] {
        let createdAgo = kSecAttrCreationDate

        return ["Rating_Item" : item,
                "Rating_rating": rating,
                "created_ago": createdAgo]
    }
    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
        let item = dict["Rating_Item"] as? String,
        let rating = dict["Rating_rating"] as? Double

            else {return nil}

        self.key = snapshot.key
        self.item = item
        self.rating = rating

    }

}
```

in my cellForRowAt function I am adding the ratings as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let rating = ratingStorage[indexPath.row]


        // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
        let ratingItemT = ratingItems[indexPath.row]


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TeamMemberRatingTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TeamMemberRatingTableViewCell

        cell.update(rating)

        cell.itemLabel.text = ratingItemT.item

        cell.cosmos.didFinishTouchingCosmos = { [ weak self] rating in
            self?.ratingStorage[indexPath.row] = rating

                let item = RatingItem(item: ratingItemT.item, rating: rating)
                self!.finalRating.append(item!)
            }




        return cell
    }

}
```

The Problem with cosmos is, that it passes the values when the user stopped touching, which means that if he changes his decision e.g. for Creativity, I get both ratings in my array -->

for example:

Creativity: 6
Creativity: 5

What I want to achieve now is, that I can delete the first rating for every double value.

Maybe someone can help! :)

Thanks

Comment: So why can't you check if `finalRating` already contains a rating for an item, and then simply remove/replace it?

Comment: I could but I am still a big noob in Coding so maybe you could give me a hint? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `finalRating` already contains an rating item, and in that case only modify the rating for that item, instead of adding a new one, something like:

```
cell.cosmos.didFinishTouchingCosmos = { [ weak self] rating in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.ratingStorage[indexPath.row] = rating
    if let existing = self.finalRating.filter ({$0.item == ratingItemT.item}).first {
        existing.rating = rating
    } else {
        let item = RatingItem(item: ratingItemT.item, rating: rating)
        self.finalRating.append(item!)
    }
}
```